# Ordenamiento de tabla con sortablejs y asignación de índice a objeto

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ordenamiento

Tengo un `array` de objetos :

```
ruta :[
    { 'order': 1, 'id': 121 },
    { 'order': 2, 'id': 123 }
]
```

el cual lo represento en una tabla usando [buefy](https://buefy.github.io/#/). A la vez, estoy utilizando la extensión [sortable.js](https://buefy.github.io/#/extensions/sortablejs) para variar el orden de las filas de la tabla al arrastrarlas:

```
const createSortable = (el, options, vnode) => {
    return Sortable.create(el, {
        ...options,
        onEnd: function (evt) {
            const data = vnode.context.ruta
            const item = data[evt.oldIndex]
            if (evt.newIndex > evt.oldIndex) {
                for (let i = evt.oldIndex; i < evt.newIndex; i++) {
                    data[i] = data[i + 1]
                }
            } else {
                for (let i = evt.oldIndex; i > evt.newIndex; i--) {
                    data[i] = data[i - 1]
                }
            }
            data[evt.newIndex] = item
            //Aquí
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                data[i].order = i + 1;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Al inicio se representa perfectamente la tabla, pero necesito que cuando varíe la posición de las filas, se actualice el valor de `order`. Por ejemplo, si el valor de `order` de la última fila es `5` y la arrastro a la primera fila, esta fila debe cambiar su valor de `order` por `1` y los demás deben actualizar su valor dependiendo de su posición en la tabla.

Intenté probando:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].order = i + 1;
}
```

Ya que quiero que empiece desde 1 el valor de `order`.

También en el `if` y el `else` de arriba intenté con:

```
if
    data[i].order = i + 1;
else
    data[i].order = i - 1;
```

Pero no funcionó.

Esta es la tabla sin ordenar donde el número es el valor del `order`:

[image: Esta es la tabla sin ordenar]

y cuando intento subir a `Andrés García` que está en la posición `4` a la posición `1` pasa esto:

[image: Imagen del problema]

Sin embargo, internamente, sí están ordenados en el `array`.

En este ejemplo debería estar `Andrés García` de primero en la fila pero lo pone abajo y así pasa con los demás.

Comment: Hola Piero Pajares, ¿qué resultados son los que estás obteniendo al verificar el ordenamiento de los elementos? Saludos.

Comment: Hola Jesús, por dentro a cada **order** les esta poniendo el valor del indice que es lo que quiero pero en la tabla no se reflejan bien los cambios. pero por dentro si lo hace. actualizare la pregunta con una captura de ejemplo

Comment: Actualizada la pregunta

Comment: Te recomendaría que abrieras un chat privado para que me expliques a detalle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te sucede se debe a la manera en que funciona [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/): *Cada vez que se actualiza el modelo, la vista es actualizada inmediatamente tomando en cuenta el cambio en el modelo*.

Cada fila de tu lista tiene como modelo un objeto dentro del `array` de datos. En tu código, cada vez que mueves una fila, varías el orden de los elementos del `array` de datos cambiando el contenido de un índice por otro, lo cual [no es detectado por `Vue`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats). Para que `Vue` detecte el cambio debes variar el `array`, por ejemplo, aplicando un `splice`. Por lo tanto, con esta operación no se varía el modelo y por consiguiente no se actualiza la vista. Intentaré describir el proceso de tu código por puntos:

1 - Cuando mueves a `Andrés García` desde la posición 4 a la posición 1, tienes un ciclo que recorre el `array` de datos y sitúa a `Andrés García` de primero dentro del mismo, es decir:

```
índice 0 del array (Carlos Sánchez) ----> (Andrés García)
índice 1 del array (Luis Chong) --------> (Carlos Sánchez)
índice 2 del array (Rosario Carranza) --> (Luis Chong)
índice 3 del array (Andrés García) -----> (Rosario Carranza)
```

2 - Pero `Vue` no ha detectado este cambio, para `Vue` la vista de la fila 4 (ahora de primera en la lista) sigue teniendo como modelo el índice 3 del `array`. Es decir:

```
Fila 1 (Andrés García) -----> el modelo es el índice 3 del array
Fila 2 (Carlos Sánchez) ----> el modelo es el índice 0 del array
Fila 3 (Luis Chong) --------> el modelo es el índice 1 del array
Fila 4 (Rosario Carranza) --> el modelo es el índice 2 del array
```

3 - Entonces llega el código que estás intentando hacer que recorre cada elemento del `array` y varía el parámetro `order`, es decir, cambias el modelo de cada fila.

4 - Al variar el modelo de cada fila, `Vue` actualiza la vista:

```
Fila 1 --> índice 3 del array (Rosario Carranza)
Fila 2 --> índice 0 del array (Andrés García)
Fila 3 --> índice 1 del array (Carlos Sánchez)
Fila 4 --> índice 2 del array (Luis Chong)
```

En mi opinión, la lógica de variar el orden de los elementos dentro del `array` está de más, no hace falta actualizar este orden ya que el mismo se está haciendo directamente en el `DOM` con `sortable.js`. Observa el siguiente código de partida sin ninguna lógica todavía para actualizar el número de `order`.:

https://codepen.io/elchininet/pen/WzqVax

Para actualizar la propiedad `order` de cada fila, una solución podría ser tener un `array` con los números de `order` y variar la posición de estos números dentro del `array` dependiendo del orden que se le de a las filas de la tabla. Después se podría actualizar el parámtro `order` de cada fila tomando en cuenta la posición que tiene cada `order` dentro del mencionado `array`. Algo así:

```
const createSortable = (el, options, vnode) => {

    // Copiar la propiedad order
    vnode.context.data.forEach( (obj) => {obj.norder = obj.order} );

    // Crear un array de orders
    const orders = vnode.context.data.map((obj) => obj.order);

    return Sortable.create(el, {
        ...options,
        onEnd: function (evt) {

            const data = vnode.context.data;      
  
            // Actualizar la posición de los orders
            orders.splice(evt.newIndex, 0, ...orders.splice(evt.oldIndex, 1));
  
            // Variar el order de cada fila
            data.forEach((obj) => {        
                obj.order = orders.findIndex((n) => n === obj.norder) + 1;
            });
  
        }
    });
};
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo funcional:

https://codepen.io/elchininet/pen/JLQqEV

**EDICIÓN: Otra solución que te he dado en SOen**

Esta solución consiste en guardar el orden de los items antes de comenzar a arrastrar una fila y una vez movida la fila, restablecer el orden al estado inicial y solo en ese momento aplicar un `splice` al `array` para que `Vue` actualice la vista:

```
const createSortable = (el, options, vnode) => {

    let order = [];

    return Sortable.create(el, {
        ...options,
        
        onStart: function (evt) {
            // when the sort starts, store the initial order of the array
            order = this.toArray();
        },

        onEnd: function (evt) {
            
            // when the sort ends, set the order to the initial state
            this.sort(order);

            // change the order using splice
            const data = vnode.context.data;
  
            data.splice(evt.newIndex, 0, ...data.splice(evt.oldIndex, 1));

            // now it is safe, you can update the order parameter
            data.forEach((o, i) => {
                o.order = i + 1;
            });

        }

    });

};
```

Ejemplo funcional: https://codepen.io/elchininet/pen/MVNaON

Comment: Si llegue a resolverlo de esa forma haciendo un splice al array pero de verdad muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder a esta pregunta y además siempre es bueno tener una segunda alternativa y que mejor solución que la tuya . Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas resuelto. Un saludo ;)

Comment: @PieroPajares, he visto que has publicado esta pregunta en SOen, te he situado [otra solución diferente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734241/table-sorting-with-index-assignment) allí.